# how to render smoke from gunshots,rockets?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

I want to make scenes with cannons and rockets firing, however I noticed for either of these particles systems just don't look right. either they look fluffy and cartoony, or if using the smoke sim the flame and smoke simply don't form the right shape and often fails to generate inexplicably. what settings should I consider when trying to simulated puffs and directed jets?

Comment: You might try this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKc8WNNV4Bw

Comment: Also, if you go to Andrew's site, he even has the finished blend file for that animation/tutorial for you to download! If you click on the About section under the YouTube video, Andrew always has a link to his tutorial on his site, and there you can download his finished blend file: http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/how-to-create-a-muzzle-flash

Comment: i would also say that you should make sure you have everything scaled properly. if the smoke or particles are being simulated on the wrong scale it could throw off the realism of the sim

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/create-a-missile-turret-scene/) might also interest you